# Sending a jQuery array back to a c# String Array

Tags: c#, jquery, arrays, model-view-controller

I have a C# method that requires a `String[]` array and I use a `$.getJSON` call to deliver the parameters to the Method in the Controller.

I am taking the values of Checkboxes that have been selected and passing them back to the Controller, however when I use `Stringify` it places if multiple values, together and when I pass the array its self, there are multiple entries, however the receiving `String[]` is null.

```
var array = new Array();
$('#ids:checked').each(function() {
    array.push($(this).val())
}

var jsonText = JSON.stringify(array); // I have tried this, but to receive one entry
var dataValues = { 
    ids: jsonText, 
    id: $('#idNumber').val(), 
    orderId: $('#orderId').val()
};

$.getJSON("/path/to/method", dataValues, function(){});
```

```csharp
public ActionResult doSomething(String[] ids, Int32 Id, Int32 OrderId)
{
    //do something here
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have a typo in your `orderId` property - the brackets are in the wrong places and the quotes are mis-matched.

Comment: Fixed that, it wasn't a copy/paste, i re-typed it all out.

Comment: It should be `JSON.stringify` not `JSON.Stringify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the value of `ids` to a JSON string; however, the server has no way of knowing that. As far as the server knows, `ids` is a `string` value, which can't be converted to `string[]`.

Instead of converting one value to JSON, you should convert the whole data object to JSON and specify its content-type:

```
var dataValues = { 
    ids: array, //the Javascript array, *not* the JSON string
    id: $('#idNumber').val(), 
    orderId: $('#orderId').val()
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/path/to/method", 
    data: JSON.stringify(dataValues),
    success: function(){},
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not posted Arrays back using GET before, I normally use POST, with something like this:

```
var sData = JSON.stringify({ ids: array});

        $.ajax({
            url: "/path/to/method",
            data: sData,
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {


            },
            error: function (result) {
            }
    });
```

In your case it might be:

```
    var dataValues = JSON.Stringify({ 
        ids: array, 
        id: $('#idNumber').val(), 
        orderId: $('#orderId').val()
    });

$.ajax({
                url: "/path/to/method",
                data: sData,
                method: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {


                },
                error: function (result) {
                }
        });

   // $.getJSON("/path/to/method", dataValues, function(){});
```